# gitlab: what is the use of before script inside a job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I feel what is the need of using `before_script` in a job. It can be put together inside the `script` itself

```
deploy-to-stage:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  script:
    -   *** some code here ***
```

If they are going to run one after another

I can understand having `before_script` common for all jobs, because it saves some boilerplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737786/99717), another use of a `before_script` definition in a job is to override the `default` `before_script`, in the case you want something different or even nothing at all in `before_script` for a specific job. The following is copy/pasted from this documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#set-a-default-before_script-or-after_script-for-all-jobs

> You can use `before_script` and `after_script` with `default`:
>
> Use `before_script` with `default` to define a default array of commands that should run before the script commands in all jobs.
> Use `after_script` with default to define a default array of commands that should run after the job completes.
> You can overwrite a default by defining a different one in a job. To ignore the default use `before_script: []` or `after_script: []`:

```
default:
  before_script:
    - echo "Execute this `before_script` in all jobs by default."
  after_script:
    - echo "Execute this `after_script` in all jobs by default."

job1:
  script:
    - echo "These script commands execute after the default `before_script`,"
    - echo "and before the default `after_script`."

job2:
  before_script:
    - echo "Execute this script instead of the default `before_script`."
  script:
    - echo "This script executes after the job's `before_script`,"
    - echo "but the job does not use the default `after_script`."
  after_script: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, machine-wise the `before_script` content and the `script` content are concatenated and executed together in a single shell, but the jobs aren't (only) read by machines.

Let's put as example your current Job, and let's suppose that I have to maintain it in a future.

If I have to change something related to the way the new code is generated or how an image has to be deployed, I can just go to the `script` section because the Job is properly defined and I don't have anything to do related to the Git configuration. On the other hand, if you have everything on that aforementioned section, then I'll have to go through all the code when probably the part I'm interested on is at the end (but it could be the case that it isn't)

Of course, this only applies when the separation between `before_script` and `script` is properly set and not a random split without any consideration.

Comment: The above note is absolutely correct, but it's also worth noting that in addition to the above, if you use `extends` or you specify a `before_script` in the root of your CI/CD config, it will also apply to all jobs. So it's another way of allowing for DRY principles if you have a set of scripts that have to run in every job.